# Can't query one view from another?

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-5.6

Okay, I'm moving a database from SQL Server (which I already miss) to MySql 5.6. I'm having a problem creating a list of valid dates. In SQL Server I just used CTEs to build up numbers, then months, then years, then days of the month, then cross join'd everything together to create a valid list. I'd rather do that then create a giant table listing all valid dates from the start to the end of time. Converting it to a set of views, however, doesn't seem to be working:

```
create view `Numbers` as
    select 0 N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
    select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9;
create view `Months` as
    select n.N+1 MonthNum union all select 11 union all select 12
    from `Numbers` n;
```

Error from MySql: Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'n' in field list.

Comment: Totally off topic here, but I'm curious as to why you are switching.

Comment: Because SQL server licensing is hideously expensive for a startup. And now that we started a MySql migration, we're seriously considering Postgres instead as it's more capable than MySql and doesn't seem to have reliability issues that I'd hoped they would have ironed out in the 6 years since I worked with it...

Comment: Makes total sense.  Have you looked at BizSpark from Microsoft? It's a program to get you all your Microsoft licenses for free for I believe 3 years.  http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx  Might make life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite the second View as follows:

```
create view `Months` as
    select N+1 MonthNum from `Numbers`
    union all select 11
    union all select 12
;
```

Here is proof

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.10-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> create view `Numbers` as
    ->     select 0 N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
    ->     select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    ->     select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> create view `Months` as
    ->     select N+1 MonthNum from `Numbers`
    ->     union all select 11
    ->     union all select 12
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

Behold the output of the Query

```
mysql> select * from Months;
+----------+
| MonthNum |
+----------+
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        3 |
|        4 |
|        5 |
|        6 |
|        7 |
|        8 |
|        9 |
|       10 |
|       11 |
|       12 |
+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Almost 2 years ? Thank you for looking back at this one and accepting :-)